# Loop not working after #Include

Tags: autohotkey

I have a main file

**AutoHotkey.ahk**:

```
#Include Script.ahk
Loop, 3
{
    Sleep, 1000
    MsgBox, Iteration number is %A_Index%.  ; A_Index will be 1, 2, then 3
}
```

and a **Script.ahk**:

```
a::b
```

The loop in my main file (AutoHotkey.ahk) does not work. However the code in the **Script.ahk** (`a::b`) works.

If I `#include` the file *after* the `loop`, both work.

What's wrong with `#include`ing the file *before* the `loop` that's making it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because without the `#include` the loop is in the autohotkey.ahk scripts auto-execute section and the auto-execute section stops when there is a return, a hotkey or a hotstring maybe more things but atleast those stop the auto-executing of the script and puts the script in to an idle state so you remap is stopping the script from ever getting to the loop. 
So when you put the include after the loop the auto-execute section is first stopped after the loop.

If you use a hotkey to start the loop you will be able to start it where ever it is in the script